# How to copy one page of a PDFDocument , to another PDFDocument

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I have a doubt about PDFDocuments. How can I copy a specific page of a PdfDocument object , to another PdfDocument object.

I've tried with the moveTo method , but It didn't worked , also Ive tried with copyPagesTo method , but I throws an Requested page is out of bounds (when I try to copy for example only one page , from 1 to 1).

Any hint?

```
List<PdfDocument> pdfDocuments = new ArrayList<>();   
PdfDocument pdfWithMultiplePages = here I have a PDF with 3 pages.
for (int i = 0 ; i<pdfWithMultiplePages.getNumberOfPages() ; i++){
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new 
    ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);    
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    pdfDocument.copyPagesTo(i+1, i+1,pdfWithMultiplePages);
    pdfWriter.close();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    shippingLabels.add(shippingLabelSplitted);
}
```

I've tried also with this :

```
List<PdfDocument> pdfDocuments = new ArrayList<>();   
PdfDocument pdfWithMultiplePages = here I have a PDF with 3 pages.
for (int i = 0 ; i<pdfWithMultiplePages.getNumberOfPages() ; i++){
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new 
    ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);    
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    pdfDocument.addPage(1,pdfWithMultiplePages.getPage(i+1));
    pdfWriter.close();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    shippingLabels.add(shippingLabelSplitted);
}
```

But it throws :

> com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Page com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage@6576eb4b cannot be added to document com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument@286ef136, because it belongs to document com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument@2c74aa66.

Comment: Please show us a [MCVE] of what you have tried.

Comment: I added a snippet in the post , im trying to achieve something like this : I have a PdfDocument with 3 pages , and I want to create 3 PdfDocuments each one with 1 different  page of the original pdf .

Comment: i think this happens when you do `i+1`, in the last iteration of the `for`, it gets out of bounds.

Comment: And how can I achieve my goal ? The getPage() starts with 1 , not with 0 . How can I copy ONLY one page each iteration?

Comment: For questions related to a specific PDF library, please also add the matching tag to your question, [tag:itext7] in your case. I just did it for you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page in a PDF has many relations to other objects in a PDF.

If you could add a page located in one document to another one, the page would reside in both documents. Thus, the page suddenly would have to have all those relations to objects in both documents. This obviously does not work, thus iText prevents this.

Instead you have to create a copy of the page(s) in question for which the relations are switched to documents in the target document.

For this task there are multiple method overloads of `PdfDocument.copyPagesTo`. Thus, these methods indeed are the ones to use.

Unfortunately you mistake source and target of the operation:

```
PdfDocument pdfWithMultiplePages = here I have a PDF with 3 pages.
....
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
pdfDocument.copyPagesTo(i+1, i+1,pdfWithMultiplePages);
```

This tries to copy page `i+1` from `pdfDocument` to `pdfWithMultiplePages`. But you just created `pdfDocument` from scratch, so it does not have any pages yet. What you most probably want is:

```
pdfWithMultiplePages.copyPagesTo(i+1, i+1, pdfDocument);
```

Comment: It throws me this error :
    Cannot copy indirect object from the document that is being written.

Comment: @Saliffanag Correct, you can only copy from PDFs which are not opened for changing, i.e. not opened with a `PdfWriter`.

Comment: @Saliffanag do you still have any open issues here?